# Rolling N Non-regular Dice in Constant Time

Tags: python, probability, dice

Say I have a non-regular dice defined by probabilities in a list that add up to one, e.g `[0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2]`. I can use the following code to simulate rolling that dice `n` times:

```py
import random
from collections import Counter
def roll(dist, n):
    sides = [i + 1 for i in range(len(dist))]
    draws = random.choices(population=sides, weights=dist, k=n)
    return Counter(draws)

print(roll([0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2], 10000000))
```

`Counter({3: 4000343, 2: 2998523, 4: 2000309, 1: 1000825})`

However, for large `n`, the code gets quite slow, as `choices` iterates `n` times.
Is there an algorithm which can simulate the dice rolls for any `n` in constant time?

Comment: AFAIK it IS in linear time, that makes it slow - 10 million iterations is just that much.
You _might_ be able to cheat it tho, as you can see, the results are already close to the probablilities, so at this point, just multiplying `n*p` would not be that big of an error - but it wouldn't be random.

Comment: Sorry, I used linear and constant wrong. The problem with finding an average like `n*p` is that it makes the rolls deterministic, what I want is not what I want. Especially when one of the probability weights are minute, an average might give you 0.4, when in reality you either get 0 or 2 etc

Comment: *"what I want is not what I want"* - Uh, what?

Comment: Apparently I can't edit, but I meant "which is not what I want". :|

Comment: If you make `dist` a list of cummulative probs then you could use a bisection method to roll the die. That would be `O(log(N))` where `N` is the number of sides.

Comment: @JohnColeman That's what they're already doing (since `random.choices` does that).

Comment: @KellyBundy I wondered if that might be the case. Out of curiosity I just checked the source. You are of course correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy has this built in as [numpy.random.Generator.multinomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.multinomial.html#numpy-random-generator-multinomial):

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter


def roll(dist, n):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    results = rng.multinomial(n, dist)
    return Counter(enumerate(results, start=1))
```

Comment: `scale` ends up close to `dist[-1]` (`p` is still `dist[-2]`).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, that comment is about a theoretical version with no special case for the final element.

Comment: Well, if we're going to go down this road, it's simpler to just use a multinomial distribution, right? Looks like numpy has that.

Comment: @RobertDodier: I don’t know, I don’t use a lot of NumPy. (This was an idea -> search -> NumPy answer.)